# Namespace for custom attribute based buildType

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, xamarin, android-xml

For debug and release buildTypes I have separate package names. From the Android docs we know the the custom attributes can be used in the XML layouts by providing a namespace for it. Namespace looks like: `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/[your package name]`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/[your package name]">

  <com.example.customviews.charting.PieChart
     custom:showText="true"
     custom:labelPosition="left" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Based on buildType, how can I construct my namespace such that it references the current package name? Could it be a string defined in Strings.xml res and this layout then references it from there? Can the namespace be dynamically created based on the current package name?

Comment: You could try to construct your namespace through the Android> Properties> Android Manifest> Package name.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Can you please elaborate on that? I'm not sure what you meant. Thanks

Comment: The way i mentioned above could change the package name of your namespace.